# How to reuse i18next instance in an express app

Tags: express, i18next

I have an express backend that I want to internationalise. I want to:

- init my i18next instance at one place
- reuse that instance on multiple places in code
- I want to use them also in model code, not only in routes

This might sound like a primitive question, but even after reading through the i18next docs, I still don't know how I should reuse the initialised i18next instance. If I use [i18next-express-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next-express-middleware), I can use the `t()` method in routes. Fine, but what do I do if I want to use it in the models or some other file, let's say in model?

I dislike the idea of passing it down to every model method via a parameter. I cannot simply do `import i18next from 'i18next'` in each file, because it would return a new instance. I can't make js-file where I would init the instance in an async function and then return it, because I can't call an async function via await in the app.js (root file of my express app). Am I trying to force it on a use case for which it wasn't built?

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

## In app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const i18next = require('i18next');
const i18nextMiddleware = require('i18next-express-middleware');
const app = express();
```

#### First configure i18next

```
i18next
  .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    preload: ['de', 'en'],
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          key: 'hello world'
        }
      }, // ...
    },
    detection: {
      // order and from where user language should be detected
      order: [/*'path', 'session', */ 'querystring', 'cookie', 'header'],

      // keys or params to lookup language from
      lookupQuerystring: 'lng',
      lookupCookie: 'i18next',
      lookupHeader: 'accept-language',
      lookupSession: 'lng',
      lookupPath: 'lng',
      lookupFromPathIndex: 0,

      // cache user language
      caches: false, // ['cookie']

      // optional expire and domain for set cookie
      cookieExpirationDate: new Date(),
      cookieDomain: `${config.Host.hostname.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '')}`,
      cookieSecure: true // if need secure cookie
    }
  });
```

#### Then register the middleware:

```
app.use(
  i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next, {
    // options
  })
);
```

#### And add a custom middleware for setting i18next instance:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  i18next.changeLanguage(req.language);
});
```

Gathered from documentation at

[expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)
[github.com/i18next/i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next)
[github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware)

Comment: Thanks, but that this way I'd have to pass the instance via function params to other modules, instead of importing it directly. I'd always have to start from a route. I would like to avoid it.